# How to access Azure Web App certs from Container

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have created a api app that runs in a container hosted in a Azure Web App service. This app needs to access to the certs that have been loaded into the azure web app service (using TLS/SSL settings).

I have tried setting the WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES to *, but not sure that this has worked.

So how do I get access to the certs, and how can I confirm that they are avialable in my container. (Or do I have to manually load the cert into my container)

Answer (score 0):

**About your first question: "not sure that this has worked".**

It is achievable to set the `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` to `*`, see here:

> The `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` app settings makes the specified
> certificates accessible to your Windows or Linux container apps
> (including built-in Linux containers) as files.

> Adding an app setting named `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` with its value
> set to the **thumbprint of the certificate** will make it accessible to
> your web application. You can have multiple comma-separated thumbprint
> values or can set this value to “ `*` “ (without quotes) in which case
> all your certificates will be loaded to your web applications personal
> certificate store.
> [image]

**About "how can I confirm that they are avialable in my container?"**

> In addition, Windows Server Core containers load the certificates into
> the certificate store automatically, in `LocalMachine\My`. To load the
> certificates, follow the same pattern as Load certificate in Windows
> apps. For Windows Nano based containers, use the file paths provided
> above to Load the certificate directly from file.

The official also offers a C# code shows how to load a public certificate in a Linux app.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

...
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("/var/ssl/certs/<thumbprint>.der");
var cert = new X509Certificate2(bytes);

// Use the loaded certificate
```

Refer to:

1. [Load certificate in Linux/Windows containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code#load-certificate-in-linuxwindows-containers)
2. [Using Certificates in Azure Websites Applications](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/)